# Overwrite one file from module in theme?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to implement a module that auto adds the streetname and city to the address in checkout.

Now I almost got it working but I need to change one function from that module. Is it possible to overwrite one of the files from the module in the theme? It's a .js file. or somehow extend it?

The problem I have is with this file:

```
  /**
     * Method to render address content on notice block
     */
    renderAddressContent: function () {
        var addressContent = '<i>';
        addressContent = '<h3>' + settings.translations.yourAddress + '</h3>';

        if (!this.source) {
            return;
        }

        var self = this;

        var address = this.source.get(this.customScope);

        $.each(address.street, function (index, street) {
            addressContent += street + ' ';
        });

        addressContent += "<br/>";
        addressContent += address.postcode;
        addressContent += "<br/>";
        addressContent += address.city;
        addressContent += "<br/>";
        addressContent += address.region;
        addressContent += "</i>";

        self.debug('Postcode: render address information');

        this.notice(addressContent);
    }
```

Since I have the region unset the address.region returns undefined which will be shown in the checkout and is really ugly. Or can I maybe somehow set region to an empty string or anything? I basically just want the word 'undefined' to be gone.

[image]

I read something about plugin's but not sure how i would use that and i am unsure if that really is what i'm looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: why can't you change the module file itself? Isn't this your own module?

Comment: No it isn't my own module. It's this module: https://github.com/wezzco/postcode-m2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement

> **I maybe somehow set region to an empty string or anything? I basically
>   just want the word 'undefined' to be gone.**

and as you telling this is third party module

So best solution is override [JS file](https://github.com/wezzco/postcode-m2/blob/master/view/frontend/web/js/view/postcode.js#L326) in your theme

Example :  Suppose your theme path is

> **app\design\frontend[VENDOR][THEME]**

and module path is

> **app\code\frontend[VENDOR][MODULE]**

In Your case module path

> app\code\frontend\Wezz\Postcode

so go to your working theme (**[VENDOR][THEME]**) and create a folder **Wezz_Postcode**

In this folder

create **web/js/view**  folder and copy then [postcode.js](https://github.com/wezzco/postcode-m2/blob/master/view/frontend/web/js/view/postcode.js) file

and do whatever change you want in this file,

So Magento will take your theme override file as first priority.

In overrided js file remove the  `addressContent += address.region;` code.

**Note :  After override JS file in your theme,Need to delete same file from `pub` folder and do `cache flush`.**

delete  postcode.js file  from pub

```
pub\static\frontend\[VENDOR]\[THEME]\[en_US | Custom Language Folder]\Wezz_Postcode\js\view\postcode.js
```

And in Console hit

**php bin/magento cache/flush**

So you will get your expected out put.